# SQL database self interaction entity

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

I've been working on a database, wich is referent to an Aeroport management. I'm having a problem that it's freaking me out.. What i'm trying to do is, assuming that a client wants to know the distance between 2 locations, in miles or kms.
 As an example, if the user wants to know the distance between London and Amsterdam, should that distance be calculated by a formule or should it be already stored on the database?

```
        (1,N) ____________  
 ____________|__          |
|              |          |
| City/Airport |<---------|
|______________|
```

How can i show to user the distance between his 2 choices?

RicardoCosta

Comment: Is it as simple as a single distance (direct line) or based on the flight path?

Comment: In general, you're going to need the formula, whether you use it to calculate on the fly, or you use it in advance to pre-calculate. In which case, it's more a matter of performance than there being a right or wrong answer. Unless you are going to be calculating millions of these, it's probably more straight forward to do it on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear. I'm going to guess that this is a student/homework problem and that your database table looks like this:

```
Airport1 Airport2 Distance
```

If there's a direct route then there's a record whose airport1 value is London and whose airport2 value is Amsterdam: if that record exists, then the distance is the value in that record.

If there's not a direct route then you need to find an indirect route: for example, a route with 1 stop-over, or 2 stop-overs, or etc.

Comment: ok, and assuming that there's a direct route, how can i make the diference between both distances? Like Amsterdam-London=400kms. How can i find the diference between them?

Comment: @RicardoCosta I don't understand your comment/question: if there's a direct route then there is only one distance (400 km). If this is a homework problem, please post if you can the entire question as originally written.

Comment: It's not a homework question. It's part of my project. Assume that the Airport is located in Paris. How can a user, introducing the 2 locations, know how many kms are from any location1 to any location2?